# Inline AutoSuggestBox like windows 11 search box

Tags: c#, autosuggest, winui

In Windows 11 OS, search textbox displays as below

[image]

Here the auto append text has a different foreground. How to do this? while typing in AutoSuggestBox, I need to show the suggestion as like in Win 11 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue on the WinUI GitHub asking about this behavior [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6960). There is no built in behavior achieving this in WinUI but you could achieve this by retemplating. Alternatively, a community member has created a control with that behavior and [published it here](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit).